# Check if promotion code exist and after redirect

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I have a promotion page. I want that page to can be visited only by users that have a code from me sent by email.

So I have this form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="promotion.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkcode(this);">
  <input name="code" type="text" id="code" maxlength="15" placeholder="Confirmation Code" required="required" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And this Javascript:

```
function checkcode ( form )
{
  var pattern = /name="code" value="|2222|1234|8888|"/g
  if (!pattern.test(form.code.value)) {
    alert( "The code is incorrect." );
    form.code.focus();
    return false ;
  }

  return true ;
}
```

This javascript code not functioning properly: if I write a bigger code with more characters will redirect; also I can't add many, if the numbers from value line come down when I write more codes/numbers will redirect, I need to add more than 100 codes. Is there any other way to get this to functioning properly? Maybe there is a PHP code that can read the codes from a file and redirect only if the code exist in that file?

And on JSFiddle redirect in any case, the javascript code just doesn't working. But if I upload on my server seems to work, but still has the error that I writed below. http://jsfiddle.net/focusoft/e9DHg/

Comment: As it is, this code will be visible to the client if they view the page source. Are you sure it is okay to have this information visible to everyone?

Comment: oh, that's right. Any good way to do what I want? And I don't want to use MySQL/Databases.

Comment: Check the code is valid server-side. You can have vague pattern-matching to reduce typos/etc, but it shouldn't be used as a security mechanism

Comment: Can I see somewhere some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Please dont do this way, try to put all codes in DB & then using AJAX to validate the code will be a better idea. if validation success try making a changing a hidden input value to something for further population. Using JS like this is a very bad idea as its client side validation. please use server side validation.

check this code, if you use Jquery, it will shorten the code & make it better. I just used plain old simple Ajax.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try{
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer
        try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e){
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function search_code(){

    var parameter1= document.getElementById('code').value;
    if (xmlHttps1==null){
    alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
    return;
    }
    var url="ajax_validate.php?para1="+encodeURIComponent(parameter1)+"&search=search";
    xmlHttps1.onreadystatechange=result_search_code;
    xmlHttps1.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttps1.send(null);
}
function result_search_code(){
    if (xmlHttps1.readyState==4){
    document.getElementById('Promotion_validation_Status').innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById('Promotion_validation_Status').innerHTML=xmlHttps1.responseText;
    }
}
var xmlHttps1=GetXmlHttpObject();
</script>


<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" onSubmit="return validate()">
  <input name="code" type="text" id="code" maxlength="15" placeholder="Confirmation Code" required="required" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="search_code()" />
</form>

<div id="Promotion_validation_Status" />
```

ajax_validate.php

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['search']=='search'){
    $promotion_code=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['para1']);
    $sql="select count(*) from table where feild_name='".$promotion_code;
    $res1=mysql_query($sql1);
    $res1=mysql_fetch_array($res1);
    if($res1['count(*)']>0){
        echo "Sucess";
        } else {
         echo "Validation Failed";
    }
}
?>
```

I think, this should give you an idea. Before you use ajax i will request to validate the format of your code using JS. so it will be easier for you to compare it with DB. This is just a basic outline for you to start this. There are so many things which i havent taken care of.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to use Databases.

Comment: Without DB, dont you thing validating this using JS will leave a big hole in your web security ?

Comment: I'm not so good in programming. Can you give me some pages where I can see some examples? I don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Do like Akhil Sidharth suggests:

Make AJAX call to PHP page passing the promocode. Do validaton within the PHP and return true or false...

You do not need DB for this.

Comment: Where I can see some coding examples?

Comment: examples of what?
AJAX call or response?

Do you use any JS framework like jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Oke, first thing, NEVER do validating like this in the javascript. This is visible for everyone! so UNSECURE! :)

How you should do this:

1. create a database table called codes with fields: code, email(if personal code) and code_active(boolean).
2. send the code (and email) using [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) or just post it to the backend.
3. check in the backend if the code is valid and return true/false.

(if you don't want to use a database, then just hardcode the codes in a php array)
NO DATABASE:

```
<?php
    $a_codes = array(1111,2222,3333,4444,5555);

    if(isset($_POST['code'])){
        if(in_array($_POST['code'], $a_codes)){
            echo "VALID CODE";
        }else{
            echo "INVALID CODE";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: just post the code to a php script then check: in_array(POST['code'],array(1,2,3,4,5,6))

Comment: I'm not sure I will know how to get this working. `$array = array(
    1 => "12345",
    2 => "22345",
);` and so on, but how to validate with the form?

Comment: Redirect anyway. Doesn't `echo`

Comment: This seems to be easiest way, but I think I don't know how to implement it in my form, because doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

assuming your code and work, and just want to expand it.

You only need to change your regular expression.

```
 /name="code" value="|2222|1234|8888|"/g
```

instead of this: `|2222|1234|8888|` 
try this: `[0-9]{4}`

where: `{number}` (is the number of characters you admit)

this way you have a rando from 0000-9999 to validate codes.

```
name="code" value="[0-9]{4}"
```

Comment: I don't want random numbers.